# How to solve 'boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp: No such file or directory'?

Tags: pcl, rosmake, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I download pcl for ros:

```
  svn co http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_electric_unstable
```

And I rosmake,it shows the error:

```
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable$ rosmake
  [ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building stack ['perception_pcl_electric_unstable']                   
  [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['perception_pcl_electric_unstable']                                 
  [ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/ira/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120708-170257                    
  [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['perception_pcl_electric_unstable'] to:
  ['flann', 'cminpack', 'pcl_ros', 'pcl']
  [ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages perception_pcl_electric_unstable.  This may take a few seconds.
  [ rosmake ] rosdep check failed to find system dependencies: libvtk-qt                                   
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common                                    
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                 
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib                                            
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                               
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
   No Makefile in package rosbuild       
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                                                 
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                                                
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                               
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                                            
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime                                          
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs                                        
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                                          
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs                              
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                                               
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean                                        
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
   No Makefile in package roslang          
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                             
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                                               
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                  
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole                                    
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph                                        
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                                              
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                                          
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy                                              
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam                                        
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster                                      
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits                              
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                                               
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                                                   
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp                                        
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                                              
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit                                          
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                                                   
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization                
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                                                
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib                                      
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> cminpack [ make ]                                                               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                 
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp                                            
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> flann [ make ]                                                                  
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< cminpack [PASS] [ 0.02 seconds ]                                                
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                                         
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                                                 
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps                            
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout                                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                                              
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                                          
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                                                
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                                          
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
   No Makefile in package roslaunch    
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< flann [PASS] [ 0.02 seconds ]                                                   
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> eigen [ make ]                                                                  
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                                
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest                                          
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< eigen ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen                                              
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> test_roslaunch [ make ]                                                         
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< test_roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package test_roslaunch                            
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> test_rosgraph [ make ]                                                          
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                                                        
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                                                 
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters                          
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]                                                            
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                                                    
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< test_rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package test_rosgraph                              
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools                  
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                                            
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools                                  
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                                                 
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                                            
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosnode [ make ]                                                                
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosnode ROS_NOBUILD in package rosnode                                          
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> timestamp_tools [ make ]                                                        
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< timestamp_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package timestamp_tools                          
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                                                 
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag                                            
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> test_nodelet [ make ]                                                           
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< test_nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package test_nodelet                                
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> test_ros [ make ]                                                               
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]                                                                 
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
   No Makefile in package rosmsg             
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbagmigration [ make ]                                                        
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< test_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package test_ros                                        
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbagmigration ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbagmigration
   No Makefile in package rosbagmigration
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> test_crosspackage [ make ]                                                      
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< test_crosspackage ROS_NOBUILD in package test_crosspackage                      
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                                          
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostopic [ make ]                                                               
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostopic ROS_NOBUILD in package rostopic                                        
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs                              
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> test_rosnode [ make ]                                                           
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< test_rosnode ROS_NOBUILD in package test_rosnode                                
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> test_rosbag [ make ]                                                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> test_topic_tools [ make ]                                                       
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< test_rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package test_rosbag                                  
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                                            
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs                                  
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                                             
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< test_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package test_topic_tools                        
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice                                    
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                                                    
  [ rosmake ] Last 40 linessservice: 19.1 sec ] [ pcl: 19.1 sec ]              [ 2 Active 52/102 Complete ]
  {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ 14%] Built target pcl_kdtree
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                                                        
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_msgs                          
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    [ 15%] Built target pcl_search
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    [ 26%] Built target pcl_features
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    [ 32%] Built target pcl_sample_consensus
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    [ 37%] Built target pcl_filters
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    [ 39%] Built target pcl_keypoints
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    [ 39%] Built target pcl_geometry
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    [ 40%] Building CXX object segmentation/CMakeFiles/pcl_segmentation.dir/src/min_cut_segmentation.cpp.o
    In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/hash_set:60,
                     from /usr/include/boost/pending/container_traits.hpp:23,
                     from /usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:31,
                     from /usr/include/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:324,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/segmentation/include/pcl/segmentation/min_cut_segmentation.h:45,
                     from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/segmentation/src/min_cut_segmentation.cpp:44:
    /usr/include/c++/4.4/backward/backward_warning.h:28: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.
    In file included from /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/segmentation/src/min_cut_segmentation.cpp:45:
    /home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/segmentation/include/pcl/segmentation/impl/min_cut_segmentation.hpp:45: fatal error: boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    make[3]: *** [segmentation/CMakeFiles/pcl_segmentation.dir/src/min_cut_segmentation.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    make[2]: *** [segmentation/CMakeFiles/pcl_segmentation.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable/pcl/build/pcl_trunk/build'
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
  [ rosmake ] Output from build of package pcl written to:
  [ rosmake ]    /home/ira/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120708-170257/pcl/build_output.log
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl [FAIL] [ 19.13 seconds ]                                                    
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosboost_cfg [ make ]                                                           
  [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pcl. 
  [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.   
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                                                 
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosboost_cfg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosboost_cfg
   No Makefile in package rosboost_cfg
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roswtf ROS_NOBUILD in package roswtf                                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> test_rospack [ make ]                                                           
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< test_rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package test_rospack                                
  [ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                     
  [ rosmake ] Built 58 packages with 1 failures.                                                           
  [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                  
  [ rosmake ] /home/ira/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120708-170257                                        
  [ rosmake ] WARNING: Rosdep did not detect the following system dependencies as installed: libvtk-qt Consider using --rosdep-install option or `rosdep install flann cminpack pcl_ros pcl`
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/sam_pcl/perception_pcl_electric_unstable$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38185/how-to-solve-%27boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp:-no-such-file-or-directory%27-?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is because PCL doesn't do a good job of keeping track of which version of boost you're using; it assumes you have the latest.

That particular thing was added to boost fairly recently, and your version of boost is too old.

You'll need a newer linux (say, Ubuntu Precise), or to install a newer boost.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-09**:
How to update boost on an older version of ubuntu? Thank you~

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-08-09**:
Build it from source; see boost.org.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-08-10**:
Is there any way to build from apt? Thank you~

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-08-11**:
You could look for a PPA; figuring that out is better-suited to an Ubuntu forum of some sort. (My machines run precise, so haven't had to figure this out for myself.)